Tenth (even) harmonic of a open-closed tube
Can I say that a frequency (let's say f1) is the "tenth harmonic" of an open-closed tube?
I would say it does not because closed tubes only have odd harmonics, is that correct??I want to check with my professor if his correction on an exam is accurrate or if he made a mistake by saying that a certain frequency is the tenth harmonic of a closed tube. I was given three sucessive frequencies heard on an open tube and the professor said that these correspond to the 10, 11 and 12 harmonics but I said it should be that way but rather 19, 21 and 23.


I'd say these are "the solutions corresponding to n=10, 11, and 12", not the 10th, 11th and 12th harmonics... but I don't work in acoustics so I don't know if they have a looser interpretation of the word harmonic in that field. In any event you may have to just go with your professor's use of terminology for as long as you're in that class.
